# Creating an instance of a COM preview handler fails on some machines

Tags: c#, wpf, com, interop

I am trying to get file previewing working in my application by using the same COM preview handlers that windows does. I am using the code found [here](http://wpffilepreviewer.codeplex.com/). On my home machine this works perfectly for all file types however at work, creating the instance of the COM handler throws the following error in most cases:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM 
class factory for component with CLSID {DC6EFB56-9CFA-464D-8880-44885D7DC193}
failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

The code that throws the error is:

```
object previewer = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

where type is the `Type` retrieved using the application GUID. I have had a good look online and on SO, and although the problem seems fairly common, I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: {DC6EFB56-9CFA-464D-8880-44885D7DC193} is handled by the Adobe PDF Preview Handler (it must be installed on the machine). Plus, this is an X86 component, is your calling code built as X86?

Comment: That guid is just an example, and I am having the issue with office previewers too. They are definitely installed, as the code reads the GUIDs from the registry in the first place. You are right, it is x86 and I am running it from a 64-bit process. I think this may be the cause of the problem as Hans has suggested below.

Comment: @Matt I've been having the same issue lately with the Adobe Reader preview handler, with an AnyCPU project running on my x64 PC. What I've discovered is that the preview handler throws this error much more often when I have the project open in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 (2010 seems to be fine). After closing VS and running the project's exe on its own it often starts working again. (Maybe someone could shed some light on this?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having problems diagnosing this failure because it is not your code that crashes.  You can find back the troublemaker with Regedit, navigate to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID and locate the {guid} reported in the error message.  You'll see it is a COM server provided by Adobe Reader, installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\pdfprevhndlr.dll on my machine.

Notable as well is that you get a COM error code that's normally associated with an out-of-process COM server, while the registered one is very much an in-process server.  This can happen when it is configured to use a surrogate, a separate process that gives the server a compatible home when you use it from a 64-bit process.  That can certainly happen, look for the AppId {guid}, you'll see the DllSurrogate value mentioned there.  It is c:\windows\syswow64\prevhost.exe, the 32-bit preview host process.  So the diagnostic is it was *that* process that crashed.

It is not uncommon to have problems with Adobe Reader.  It is a program that entered its terminal stage a while ago, every new release is worse than its previous version.  It sure looks to me like Adobe lost control over it, probably with a code base that is no longer maintainable and not enough programmers working on it that still know how it works.

First look in the Windows event log, there ought to be a diagnostic about the crash in the Application event log.  Maybe it will tell you something useful.  Next thing to do is avoid exercising its ability to run in a surrogate.  Change your main EXE to a 32-bit process.  For a .NET app you do so with Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target from AnyCPU to x86.  If it still crashes then at least you'll have a better shot at debugging it since the crash will now occur inside of your process.  Reinstalling Adobe Reader *may* provide relieve, albeit that completely uninstalling it is getting to be a pretty attractive proposition these days.

If this only occurs on your user's machine then you certainly have a nasty support problem.  Do give them an update with the changed Platform target setting.  If that doesn't help then you are pretty much stuck with advising them to find support at Adobe or updating or uninstalling Reader.

Comment: Hans thanks for this great answer, it has helped a lot! Building as x86 makes this problem go away, so I think the issues is with prevhost.exe. I was not only seeing the exception with pdfs, but office files too, so this backs up that conclusion. The next step is to figure out why it is failing.

Comment: No, prevhost.exe is not the problem.  It doesn't actually do anything but provide a host process for 32-bit preview providers.  It is one of those providers that falls over, taking the process down too.  Like the crapware that Adobe ships.  Well, you're ahead it seems.